# ERRNO: 8|TEXT:Undefined index

Tags: php, mysqli, undefined-index

i'm having a problem with my php code: browser show me this error: ERRNO: 8|TEXT:Undefined index:N° Asset con guasti
i'm trying to do dinamic table taking data from a database, but something with the 'fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)' function  must have gone wrong

```
<?php 
require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
require_once('error_handler.php');
require_once('config.php');
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, 'Elia', '1234', 'test');

//query SQL da eseguire
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `livello_di_servizio`';     

//esegue la query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
.
.
.
.
.
.
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
//errore (undefined index)
echo "<tr><td class='tab_sx' style='text-align: left'>".$row['Etichette di riga']."</td>";
echo "<td class='gruppo' style='text-align: center'>".$row['Numero Macchine']."</td>";
echo "<td class='gruppo' style='text-align: right'>".$row['Ore Pianificate Mese']."</td>";
echo "<td class='gruppo' style='text-align: center'>".$row['N° Asset con guasti']."</td>";
echo "<td class='gruppo' style='text-align: right'>".$row['DT Periodo']."</td>";
echo "<td class='tab_guasti_top' style='text-align: center'>".$row['N° Guasti Totali']."</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFF' class='tab_dx' style='text-align: right'>".$row['QT \(Indisponibilità\)']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table></div></div>";?>
```

Comment: `N° Asset con guasti` row probably does not exist in the database...

Comment: 'N° Asset con guasti row probably does not exist in the database...'
all parameters are in the database..

Comment: Can you show use your table ? "EXPORT TABLE ..."

Comment: i'm not able to post table code, it say:It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

and the 'export->table' option isn's available

Comment: Solved!
the problem were slashs first and before () of 'QT \(Indisponibilità\)'. I took them off and now everything is working well.
ty u all for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hm. might be a problem with encoding : 
try to add this after the `$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, 'Elia', '1234', 'test');` :

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

if it doesn't work, juste don't use space or special char (like `°`) in your row name, it's a very poor practice.

and also, please print out the `$row` array :

```
print_r($row);
```

Comment: there is already in metatag
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Then do as @Kevin say, show us the table with the command `EXPORT TABLE` in the mysql console and give us the output of the `print_r($row);` in your script

Comment: I have to use the space because into the database is saved to the same; if I do otherwise gives me error